# How can I pull data from multiple sql tables using a join statement

Tags: sql

I'm designing a simple in-office ticket system, and would like to include a field for the party responsible for the next action. To do so right this moment I'm thinking of using `tableName` and `tableID` as specifiers for the specific responsible party (could be a technician, customer, or third party, all in different tables)

It would be fine to pull that data in and run another select call using the name of the table as a parameter, but the extra data flow slows things down significantly.

Is there a way to use a single join statement to return the details of the party with a column for the table name and one for the individual table id or is there a better way to store the data from multiple potential tables?

Comment: It might be simpler to put the technicians / customers / third parties into a single table with a field to differentiate between the types of party. You could then use a foreign key to that table, which should improve efficiency. If you must have the party types in separate tables, you could have separate fields in the ticket table, each a foreign key to the various tables. I can't get more specific without more detail (your RDBMS, table structures): your question is pretty wide open.

Comment: An alternative to the single table might be to present a union of multiple tables as a view.  The performance would be unlikely to be great, and you'd be responsible for ensuring unique ids (as you already are!).  If the database is PostgreSQL, you could use table inheritance and reparent the individual tables.

Comment: are there only these 3 parties or more than that ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, life gets busy! Politank-Z: That does sound fairly nice, I considered using a "contact" table that holds the contact information for a user, bypassing the need for the separate tables. Mihir Shah: Yeah, just the three, though that's not guaranteed to be static..

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join to achieve your requirement :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @OfficeTickets Table
(
     Id             Int Identity(1,1)
    ,Column1        Varchar(100)
    ,PartyType      Varchar(1)
    ,TechnicianId   Int Null
    ,CustomerId     Int Null
    ,ThirdPartyId   Int Null
)

Declare @OfficeTickets1 Table
(
     Id             Int Identity(1,1)
    ,Column1        Varchar(100)
    ,TableName      Varchar(100)
    ,TableId        Int Null
)

Declare @Technician Table
(
     Id             Int Identity(1,1)
    ,TechnicianName Varchar(100)
)

Declare @Customers Table
(
     Id             Int Identity(1,1)
    ,CustomerName   Varchar(100)
)

Declare @ThirdParty Table
(
     Id             Int Identity(1,1)
    ,ThirdPartyName Varchar(100)
)

Insert Into @Technician(TechnicianName) Values
 ('Technician_1')
,('Technician_2')
,('Technician_3')

Insert Into @Customers(CustomerName) Values
 ('Customer_1')
,('Customer_2')
,('Customer_3')

Insert Into @ThirdParty(ThirdPartyName) Values
 ('ThirdParty_1')
,('ThirdParty_2')
,('ThirdParty_3')
,('ThirdParty_4')

Insert Into @OfficeTickets(Column1,PartyType,TechnicianId,CustomerId,ThirdPartyId) Values
 ('ABC','T',3,Null,Null)
,('XYZ','C',Null,2,Null)
,('PUQ','P',Null,Null,4)

Insert Into @OfficeTickets1(Column1,TableName,TableId) Values
 ('ABC','Technician',3)
,('XYZ','Customers',2)
,('PUQ','ThirdParty',4)

---- taken separate columns for parties
Select   ot.Id
        ,ot.Column1
        ,t.TechnicianName
        ,c.CustomerName
        ,tp.ThirdPartyName
From    @OfficeTickets As ot
        Left Join @Technician As t On ot.PartyType = 'T' And ot.TechnicianId = t.Id
        Left Join @Customers As c On ot.PartyType = 'C' And ot.CustomerId = c.Id
        Left Join @ThirdParty As tp On ot.PartyType = 'P' And ot.ThirdPartyId = tp.Id

---- by TableName and TableId
Select   ot.Id
        ,ot.Column1
        ,t.TechnicianName
        ,c.CustomerName
        ,tp.ThirdPartyName
From    @OfficeTickets1 As ot
        Left Join @Technician As t On ot.TableName = 'Technician' And ot.TableId = t.Id
        Left Join @Customers As c On ot.TableName = 'Customers' And ot.TableId = c.Id
        Left Join @ThirdParty As tp On ot.TableName = 'ThirdParty' And ot.TableId = tp.Id
```

**output:-**

[image]